# "-bash: is a directory" is this an error?

Tags: linux, oracle

When i logging with "oracle" user (su - oracle), "-bash: /home/oracle: is a directory" warning appears.
Is an error? This warning was not happening on my other virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is trying to execute the string "/home/oracle" as a bash command.

If this happens at each login, it's possible such a command has been added to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, e.g.

```
# mkdir /home/oracle

# echo '/home/oracle' >> /home/myuser/.bashrc

# su - myuser
Last login: Thu Aug 20 20:44:19 CEST 2020 on pts/0
-bash: /home/oracle: Is a directory
```

Comment: here is a command like that :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                # Get the aliases and functions                                                                                                      if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] ; then                                                                                                                                 
    . ~/.bashrc                   fi

Comment: could this be the reason?

Comment: @zayit I think you should review the contents of the `/home/oracle/.bashrc` file and perhaps compare it to the other VM where you said you don't have this problem.